# SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' when running Jest React native

Tags: react-native, ts-jest

I'm learning how to write unit tests in React Native. I am using ingnite boilerplate to create a react native app.And i followed this guide(https://ignitecookbook.com/docs/recipes/GeneratorComponentTests/) to create component test files.

But now I'm getting

```
 ● Test suite failed to run

    Jest encountered an unexpected token

    Jest failed to parse a file. This happens e.g. when your code or its dependencies use non-standard JavaScript syntax, or when Jest is not configured to support such syntax.

    Out of the box Jest supports Babel, which will be used to transform your files into valid JS based on your Babel configuration.

    By default "node_modules" folder is ignored by transformers.

    Here's what you can do:
     • If you are trying to use ECMAScript Modules, see https://jestjs.io/docs/ecmascript-modules for how to enable it.
     • If you are trying to use TypeScript, see https://jestjs.io/docs/getting-started#using-typescript
     • To have some of your "node_modules" files transformed, you can specify a custom "transformIgnorePatterns" in your config.
     • If you need a custom transformation specify a "transform" option in your config.
     • If you simply want to mock your non-JS modules (e.g. binary assets) you can stub them out with the "moduleNameMapper" config option.

    You'll find more details and examples of these config options in the docs:
    https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration
    For information about custom transformations, see:
    https://jestjs.io/docs/code-transformation

    Details:

    /Users/giahuy/PizzaApp/app/components/specs/Profile.spec.tsx:12
            (0, react_native_1.render)(<Profile_1.Profile />);
                                       ^

    SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'
```

Here is my Profile component.

```
import * as React from "react"
import { StyleProp, TextStyle, View, ViewStyle } from "react-native"
import { observer } from "mobx-react-lite"
import { colors, typography } from "app/theme"
import { Text } from "app/components/Text"

export interface ProfileProps {
  /**
   * An optional style override useful for padding & margin.
   */
  style?: StyleProp<ViewStyle>
}

/**
 * Describe your component here
 */
export const Profile = observer(function Profile(props: ProfileProps) {
  const { style } = props
  const $styles = [$container, style]

  return (
    <View style={$styles}>
      <Text style={$text}>Hello</Text>
    </View>
  )
})

const $container: ViewStyle = {
  justifyContent: "center",
}

const $text: TextStyle = {
  fontFamily: typography.primary.normal,
  fontSize: 14,
  color: colors.palette.primary500,
}
```

and test file

```
// https://reactnativetesting.io/component/testing/

import React from "react"
import { render, screen } from "@testing-library/react-native"
import { Profile } from "../Profile"

describe("Profile", () => {
  it("renders", () => {
    render(<Profile />)
    expect(screen.getByText("Hello")).toBeTruthy()
  })
})
```

and here my jest.config.js

```
const { defaults: tsjPreset } = require("ts-jest/presets")

/** @type {import('@jest/types').Config.ProjectConfig} */
module.exports = {
  ...tsjPreset,
  preset: "react-native",
  transformIgnorePatterns: [
    "<rootDir>/node_modules/(react-clone-referenced-element|@react-native-community|react-navigation|@react-navigation/.*|@unimodules/.*|native-base|react-native-code-push)",
    "jest-runner",
  ],
  setupFiles: ["<rootDir>/test/setup.ts"],
  transform: {
    "^.+\\.spec.tsx?$": [
      "ts-jest",
      {
        tsconfig: "<rootDir>/test/test-tsconfig.json",
      },
    ],
  },
}
```

I don't know what the promblem is .Does anyone know what problem it has?.
Thanks for helping

Comment: Jest doesn't understand ES6+ so, I guess you have to mock this `mobx-react-lite` and `app/components/Text` (where *Hello* text is wrapped) to let know jest and get the result that you're looking for.